# error: model is not define ,after calling from directory

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I instantiated my models and saved inside the directory

```
#instantiation of lstm unit
net1=LSTM_net(input_size=512,hidden_size=512, output_size=101,cnn_net=resnet)
model_save_name = 'net1_spatial_stream.pt'
torch.save(net1.state_dict(), MODELS_PATH_SPATIAL)
```

when I load a model from a directory

```
model_save_name = 'net1_spatial_stream.pt'
net1.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODELS_PATH_SPATIAL))
net1=net1.cuda()#pass to gpu
```

shows error

```
 1 model_save_name = 'net1_spatial_stream.pt'
 ----> 2 net1.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODELS_PATH_SPATIAL))
  3 net1=net1.cuda()#pass to gpu

 NameError: name 'net1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`load_state_dict()` method just load the weights into the model, you have to define the model first. Its like You have to initialize the model and then use load_state_dict() like this,

```
net1=LSTM_net(input_size=512,hidden_size=512, output_size=101,cnn_net=resnet)
model_path = 'net1_spatial_stream.pt'
net1.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
net1=net1.cuda()#pass to gpu
```

Also you have to pass the exact path with which you saved the model.